# Error select max(convert(varchar(10),field1 )) + 1 from table

Tags: sql-server

In one of the database tables, I have a Varchar type field that has a series of records as follows:

```
Table
    
Field1
D0001
D0002
D0003
```

What I'm trying to do is select max(field1) from the Table + 1. It's like a sequence number, every I select the query should be increment + 1.
So the desired result should be;

```
Table
        
Field1
D0001
D0002
D0003
D0004
```

I have tried using this query, but it's not working.

```
select max(convert(varchar(10),field1 )) + 1 as field1 from Table
```

I got an error message like this;

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'D0003' to data
> type int.

Comment: `1` is an `int`, and `'D0003'` is a `varchar`; the 2 do not mix. Perhaps you want `+ '1'`, which would concatenate the string to the end, giving `'D00031'`.

Comment: @Larnu : I'm so sorry, I did not get the point. Would you please give me an example ?

Comment: The `+ '1'` was the example... Note there that single quotes (`'`) around the `1`.

Comment: And what do you expect when the max value is 'D9999'?

Comment: Just wondering why you are trying to reinvent the wheel, when SQL Server has perfectly good `SEQUENCE` and `IDENTITY`

Comment: Why are you trying to munge D, 000 and an integer all together? Use an identity for you numbering, store the D separately and display them however you wish in your presentation / reporting layer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE 
(
field1 NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @Table(Field1)VALUES(N'D0001')
INSERT INTO @Table(Field1)VALUES(N'D0002')
INSERT INTO @Table(Field1)VALUES(N'D0003')
INSERT INTO @Table(Field1)VALUES(N'D0004')

select max(CONVERT(BIGINT , substring(field1,patindex('%[0-9]%', field1),len(field1)))) + 1 as field1 from @Table
```

**Result:**

| field1 |
| --- |
| 5 |